# Bootstrap 5 and Flask not able to set active class on current html page

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am building a flask web-app and I am now working on the nav-bar. I am using bootsrap 5 to style. Now I am trying to set the the class=active when I click on the navbar specific page with this code

```
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
             <ul>
                <li class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'edit_profile' else '' }}">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('auth.edit_profile') }}">Link 1</a>
                </li>

                <li class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'menu2' else '' }}">
                    <a href="/blah2"> Link 2 </a>
                </li>

              </ul>
         </nav>
```

this code is in my base.html template

then to each individual template I add

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% set active_page = "edit_profile.html" %}
```

however whenever I click on Link1 it doesn't "stay active". I can see it changing colour when I hover over it when the mouse but when clicked it then doesn't stay active.

How can I make the navbar item stay item when I have clicked on it?

What is my code missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `endpoint` attribute of the `request` object to test whether to add the `active` class. The implementation for Bootstrap 5 would then look something like this.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a 
                class="nav-link{% if request.endpoint == 'auth.edit_profile' %} active{% endif %}" 
                href="{{ url_for('auth.edit_profile') }}"
            >Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```